# Is there a way to automatically format R code in data.table syntax?

Tags: r, data.table, rstudio

When writing the code in data.table format as shown below

[image]

Is there a possible way of making sure that when I use the RStudio code reformatter `cmd + shift + A`, the code is formatted as above, instead of as shown below;

[image]

Comment: I think not, unfortunately. The RStudio IDE relies (I believe) on the `styler` package, which *"only support[s] the tidyverse style guide and I don't see this formatting compatible with it"* https://github.com/r-lib/styler/issues/720#issuecomment-769711869. See that comment for possible hacks to get what you want.

Comment: As an aside, setDT works in place. You can use just setDT(df) or, if you really do want a copy of the whole thing, df_copy <- as.data.table(df)

Comment: you can try VS code, there should be some extensions for the styling

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not going the direction you want it to (offset stacking), but one way of neatly 'stacking' your chained calls is to use base R's `|>` pipe (added in R 4.1) and `_` placeholder (added in R 4.3) to make your subsequent calls indent neatly across lines. e.g.:

```r
dt |>
  _[do this] |>
  _[then this] |>
  _[and finally this]
```

That's more along `styler`'s lines. The pipe and `_` don't add any extra steps as R parses them as if chained in normal syntax:

```r
library(data.table)

mtcars_dt <- as.data.table(mtcars)

expr <- quote(mtcars_dt |>
                _[, .N, by = .(cyl)] |>
                _[order(-N)] |>
                _[, .(mean = mean(N), sd = sd(N))])

expr
#> mtcars_dt[, .N, by = .(cyl)][order(-N)][, .(mean = mean(N), sd = sd(N))]

eval(expr)
#>        mean       sd
#> 1: 10.66667 3.511885
```

Comment: Note this needs at least R 4.3 or you'll get `Error: pipe placeholder can only be used as a named argument`.

Comment: Thank you very much, but does it reduce the speed of the data.table codes in any way?

Comment: It shouldn't as R is evaluating both routes as equivalent syntax. I've added a bit above to glimpse how R reads a `|>` pipe chain - it essentially reads the stacked lines as a set of chained square brackets exactly as the normal syntax would be written and evaluates accordingly.

Comment: TIL about the ability to use `_` in this fashion ... reinforcing SamR's "4.3" comment, but dang that's smooth!

Comment: @AndyBaxter Note that the output (source code) when using `quote()` or `substitute()` functions shows the exact source code non-piped equivalent of the original code compared to using `expression()` function that prepends the output with _expession_. The output of `quote(mtcars_dt |> _[, .N, by = .(cyl)])` or `substitute(mtcars_dt |> _[, .N, by = .(cyl)])` is `mtcars_dt[, .N, by = .(cyl)]` while the output of `expression(mtcars_dt |> _[, .N, by = .(cyl)])` is `expression(mtcars_dt[, .N, by = .(cyl)])`. The output using `quote/substitute` looks a bit cleaner

Comment: Thank you @B.ChristianKamgang that's a better way to display the inner workings. Will update answer to give the clearer outputs. And thanks SamR for clarifying - had remembered it was recently added but couldn't remember which version.